# How to edit any text in chosen editor?

Tags: mac, applications, text-editor

I'm looking for a small app that will let me move any selected text (ie in a text box or another app) into my chosen text editor (in this case Sublime Text 2), and when I save will move it back to where it came from. I remember reading about such a thing ages ago, and google has failed me. Please tell me what I can do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this

http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/quickcursor

what you're thinking of?

> QuickCursor brings your favorite text editor* to any app with a global keyboard shortcut. Unlike manually copying and pasting between apps, QuickCursor automates the entire process to save you time.

To use [Sublime Text 2](http://sublimetext.com/) with QuickCursor, add it's bundle ID (com.sublimetext.2) to the custom bundle ID field in the QuickCursor preferences.